# Extending boost variant with an MPL list

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I'm trying to provide a program a way to add new objects to a variant in a library but I'm encountering some cryptic errors.

```cpp
#include <boost/mpl/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/joint_view.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>

struct InternalType1 {};
struct InternalType2 {};

template <typename LocalTypes>
struct Foo
{
  typedef boost::mpl::list<
    InternalType1,
    InternalType2
  > Types;

  typename boost::make_variant_over<
    typename boost::mpl::joint_view<
      Types,
      LocalTypes
    >::type
  >::type container_;

  // typename boost::make_variant_over<
  //   typename boost::mpl::copy<
  //     LocalTypes,
  //     boost::mpl::back_inserter<Types>
  //   >::type
  // >::type container_;
};

struct LocalType1 {};
struct LocalType2 {};

int main()
{
  typedef boost::mpl::list<
    LocalType1,
    LocalType2
  > Types;

  Foo<Types> foo;
}
```

By using a `mpl::joint_view` (which I assume if the most efficient way of achieving this), I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/clear.hpp:29:7: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
```

By uncommenting the other attempt, using `mpl::copy`, and replacing it with the original, then the error changes:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/aux_/push_back_impl.hpp:40:9: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
```

Which, interestingly, has the [following comment](https://github.com/boostorg/mpl/blob/master/include/boost/mpl/aux_/push_back_impl.hpp#L40):

```
// should be instantiated only in the context of 'has_push_back_impl';
// if you've got an assert here, you are requesting a 'push_back' 
// specialization that doesn't exist.
```

Neither of these errors make any sense to me as, w/r/t the first, I don't see which templates are not complete and for the second, which push_back specialization I'm not using?

Comment: The second one is pretty easy to understand, [`mpl::list`](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/list.html) can't be used with `push_back`. You could use `boost::mpl::front_inserter<Types>` or simply use a `mpl::vector` in your `Types` typedef.

Comment: Aaaah, yeah that's it. Thanks! I'll leave the question open due to the joint_view solution probably being the better or the two to do in production.

Comment: I don't see a better way unless you intend to modify `make_variant_over`. `mpl::copy` from `mpl::vector`s is the way if you ask me

Comment: So is the `joint_view` not a feasible thing to do here? It says in the documentation for [`make_variant_over`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/make_variant_over.html) that it requires an MPL Sequence. And then the [`joint_view`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/joint-view.html) docs state that joint_view is a Forward Sequence. So these two should be compatible, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `boost::mpl::clear<>` is not implemented for a `joint_view`... hence the huge compiler dump terminating with:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/clear.hpp:29:7: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'boost::mpl::clear_impl<boost::mpl::aux::joint_view_tag>::apply<boost::mpl::joint_view<boost::mpl::list<InternalType1, InternalType2, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::mpl::list<LocalType1, LocalType2, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> > >'
```

(I don't know how to format that properly)

This could be just an oversight in the library, or it may just not be clear *which* empty Sequence type should be returned in this case. If you want to use a `joint_view`, you'll have to provide a specialization of `clear_impl` somewhere:

```
namespace boost { namespace mpl {
   template <>
   struct clear_impl<aux::joint_view_tag>
   {
       template <typename JV>
       struct apply {
           typedef list<> type; // since you're using list I figured
                                // I would too.
       };
   };
} }
```

With that, your code compiles for me on both gcc and clang.

Alternatively, if adding stuff into `namespace boost::mpl` strikes you as a little shady but you still want to stick with `list`s, you can just use [`insert_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/insert-range.html):

```
typename boost::make_variant_over<
    typename boost::mpl::insert_range<
        Types,
        typename boost::mpl::end<Types>::type,
        LocalTypes
    >::type
>::type container_;
```

Comment: That seems to be it, thanks! I guess, taking this into context, an `mpl::copy` and `mpl::vector` really does sound like the best choice. Like you said, an empty `mpl::joint_view` doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: @SamKellett Can actually use the same `insert_range` metafunction with `vector` too. Either way, you end up with the same thing.